# Mysql - join two tables without losing relevant values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-analysis

I have two tables representing a database for customer products and its competitors' products:

`tmp_match` - from_product_id and to_product_id representing matches between customer product and competitor product respectively.

`tmp_price_history` - shows the price of each product per date.

I am trying to write a query which will list all dates from table `tmp_price_history`. For each date I want to see customer product price vs competitor product price according to product matches pairs in table `tmp_match`, regardless of whether there was a price history record **for customer product or competitor product or both**:

if both prices are available for a specific date - list them both in their columns

if there is only a record for customer product - show only customer price (and leave the competitor column blank).

if there is only record for competitor product - show competitor price in its column.

Expected result:

```
date    from_product_id to_product_id   cust_price  comp_price
1       1               11              99          95
2       1               11              98          94
1       1               12                          92
2       1               12                          91
2       2                               108
```

I tried to achieve that using this query:

```
 select cust_hist.date, from_product_id, to_product_id, cust_hist.price as cust_price,comp_hist.price as comp_price
from tmp_match as matches
       left join tmp_price_history cust_hist
         on cust_hist.product_id = matches.from_product_id
       left join tmp_price_history comp_hist
         on  comp_hist.product_id = matches.to_product_id
;
```

but it doesn't achieve my goal as can be seen in this [sql snippet](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f3a8f/2).